# Python: How to sort a list by given value in inner dictionary?

Tags: python, list

I have a list, which looks like this:

```
C = [
      [129211, [{'cid': 142211, 'date': 1478550075, 'likes': {'count': 40}]
      [128732, [{'cid': 142061, 'date': 1478550100, 'likes': {'count': 17}]
      ...
    ]
```

How to get a copy of this list sorted by values of 'count' in 'likes' (in this case it's 40 and 17)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use an appropriate sort key.

```
C = [
      [129211, [{'cid': 142211, 'date': 1478550075, 'likes': {'count': 40}}]],
      [128732, [{'cid': 142061, 'date': 1478550100, 'likes': {'count': 17}}]]
    ]
s = sorted(C, key=lambda i: i[1][0]['likes']['count'])
```

Note that your current list `C` is not properly structured - I've repaired the incorrect syntax.

Result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(s)
[[128732, [{'cid': 142061, 'date': 1478550100, 'likes': {'count': 17}}]],
 [129211, [{'cid': 142211, 'date': 1478550075, 'likes': {'count': 40}}]]]
```